# Determining the residue of a function

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the function $f(z)=(1-e^{2z})/z^4$ and I have tried to work out the residue using the method $res(f(z);a) = g^{m-1}(a)/(m-1)!$ however when I use the singularity at $z=0$, I and still dividing by zero if I'm correct.

So I have found the Taylor Series of the function and am aware that the residue is given by the coefficient of $z^{-1}$ which in my case in $-4/3$.

My question is, why can I take the coefficient of $z^{-1}$ to be the residue? What's the reasoning behind this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I am not sure what your $g$ is, but the method you mention looks similar to $$res(f(z);a)=lim_{z\rightarrow a}(\frac{1}{(m-1)!}\frac{d^{m-1}}{dz^{m-1}}f(z)(z-a)^m)$$ Applying this, $$res(f(z);0)=\frac{1}{3!}\frac{d^{3}}{dz^{3}}(1-e^{2z})|_{z=a}=-\frac{8e^{2z}}{6}|_{z=a}=-4/3.$$ So there won't be any issue with the singularity at $z=0$.

---

As with your issue about why the residue is the coefficient of $z^{-1}$ in the Laurent/Taylor series, this can be shown as follows:
Suppose $f$ has a Laurent series about some point $z=a$, say $\sum_{-\infty}^\infty a_n(z-a)^n$. Then from the definition, $$res=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_\gamma f(z)dz=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_\gamma \sum a_n (z-a)^ndz=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\sum a_n\oint_\gamma (z-a)^ndz.$$ Then since $f$ has this Laurent series, it is analytic within some annulus, so $\gamma$ can be deformed to a circle of radius $r$, and thus $z$ can be parametrised as $z=re^{i\theta}$, giving $$res=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\sum a_n\int_0^{2\pi} r^n e^{in\theta}ire^{i\theta} d\theta=\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum a_n r^{n+1}\int_0^{2\pi} e^{i(n+1)\theta}d\theta.$$
This $RHS=a_{-1}$ when $n=-1$ and the integral is $0$ otherwise, so $res=a_{-1}$.

Comment: My issue was that I was multiplying the function by $(z-a)$ rather than $(z-a)^m$ and thank you very much for the explanation about the coefficient of $z^{-1}$

Comment: Sorry for the notification, I was being silly haha.